# Simple price indices question

Tags: time-series, arithmetic

If the inflation indices was reset to 100 in the the 3rd quarter, what would be the fourth quarter inflation index for food. I have no idea how to do this . Below is the graph:

[image]

Comment: This was closer to on-topic on math.stackexchange than it is here. Not every aspect of every statistic is a statistical issue. You need to know the definition of an inflation index from economics, and then it is a simple calculation. Is this a homework question, and has your textbook covered how inflation is calculated? By the way, the word "indices" is the plural of index.

Comment: Those are presumably price indices rather than inflation indices.

Comment: @Henry Could you be so kind to change the title of the question appropriately ? I think I am not qualified, but "Simple Statistics Question" is terrible.

Comment: This looks like a SHL psychometric test question that you've screenshotted.

Comment: @DouglasZare Assuming that the unedited spelling was "indexes", then "indexes" actually gets a lot of use in economics literature. Quick browse of English forums on this matter reveals that both are correct.

Comment: @Shaniqueia: The point I was making was not about how to spell the plural, but not to use it as a singular. Anyway, you can see that the spelling wasn't changed in Henry's edit by clicking on the time of the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Now, the inflation index is reset to 100% at the 1st quarter. We can see that the 3rd- and 4th-quarter values of Foods are 95% and 94%, respectively.

If the index was reset to 100% at the 3rd quarter, the 4th-quarter index would be $94\% / 95\% \approx 99\%$.